# Who to implement UIBezierPath class in the UIViewController class?

Tags: swift, class

Why i can't using UIBezierPath class in UIViewController class directly without using any View class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you can't draw on a controller, you draw on a view. To demonstrate, If UIBezierPath class is a pen, the view is your paper and the code you put in the view's dreawRect() method is like your hand which uses a pen (UIBezierPath) to draw.

The viewController is so unrelated that you can say its a bag for your papers.